# Finite differences and Taylor error

Tags: taylor-expansion, finite-differences

Im trying to do some numerical analysis using finite differences method, but have some questions:

There is an analitical solution $u(x,t)$ and the numerical estimation $U_n(x,t)$. I want to compare their spatial variation and in order to do it I take the Taylor series like this:

$$U_n(x_j+\Delta x,t)=U_n(x_j,t)+\Delta x\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(x_j,t)}+\frac{(\Delta x)^2}{2!}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_{(x_j,t)}$$

Now i can make

$$\frac{U_n(x_j+\Delta x,t)-U_n(x_j,t)}{\Delta x}-\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(x_j,t)}=\frac{\Delta x}{2!}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_{(x_j,t)}$$
And later i estimated this difference by $C(\Delta x)$, where C is a bound for $\bigg|\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\bigg|$

The problem is that i check in some books and they say that the estimation is 
$C(\Delta x+\Delta t)$ but i cant noticed why....

Comment: It depends on the PDE you are solving and kind of discretization you are using for the temporal term. Are you applied the Finite difference method to a specific class of PDE?

Comment: Yes, im working with  Hamilton Jacobi $u_t+H(u_x)=0$

Comment: Nice, so you can discretize the temporal derivative as well, the overall error for consistency is contributed from space error and temporal error. For example, I use euler explicit for temporal derivative, the error I get is O($\delta$ t) similar to the space part. You can combine both the errors in terms of O($\delta t$ + $\delta x$)

Comment: Then no matter what  difference i want to estimate  ( space or temporal) the error is $O(\Delta t + \Delta x)$? Do you now some book to read about more strict proof?  thx!

Comment: No no it depends on the PDE you are working with and kind of dicretization you would do for space part and time part, if you higher order suppose for time part that would change. Yes, this a good book on finite difference methods (https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898717938)